# Spring gradle: Program return null in Java class but not in PHPMyadmin

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, discord

This is my first time making a discord bot that attached to a DB using spring boot and Gradle. I followed some tutorials and the discord bot is working properly but when I want to call my DB it returns null in my Java. I tried to use the same query in my PHPmyadmin to see if it is really a null but in reality, it should have returned a value.

This is my Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);

    /**
     * The entrance point of our program.
     *
     * @param args The arguments for the program. The first element should be the bot's token.
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        if (args.length < 1) {
//            System.err.println("Please provide a valid token as the first argument!");
//            return;
//        }

        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);

        // Enable debugging, if no slf4j logger was found
        FallbackLoggerConfiguration.setDebug(true);

        // The token is the first argument of the program
        String token = "Nzg3NTI4MTU0MDM3MjIzNDU2.X9WQvw.Ix9zeiZB5KWwGkxfUAU0pjy4xF0";

        // We login blocking, just because it is simpler and doesn't matter here
        DiscordApi api = new DiscordApiBuilder().setToken(token).login().join();

        // Print the invite url of the bot
        logger.info("You can invite me by using the following url: " + api.createBotInvite());

    

        // Add listeners
        api.addMessageCreateListener(new CommandManager("!")); // <-- I want to run this command

        // Log a message, if the bot joined or left a server
        api.addServerJoinListener(event -> logger.info("Joined server " + event.getServer().getName()));
        api.addServerLeaveListener(event -> logger.info("Left server " + event.getServer().getName()));
    }

}
```

From there, it should lead me to my CommandManager.java within my Command directory

```
public class CommandManager implements MessageCreateListener {
    String prefix="!";
    DieCommand dieCommand = new DieCommand();
    EightBallCommand eightBallCommand = new EightBallCommand();
    UserInfoCommand userInfoCommand = new UserInfoCommand();
    NijiMemberCommand nijiMemberCommand = new NijiMemberCommand();
    CurrencyConverterCommand currencyConverterCommand = new CurrencyConverterCommand();

    public CommandManager(String pfx) {
        this.prefix = pfx;
    }


    @Override
    public void onMessageCreate(MessageCreateEvent event) throws NullPointerException {
        String[] command = event.getMessageContent().split(" ");
        if(command[0].contains(prefix+"roll")){
            dieCommand.onMessageCreate(event);
            return;
        }
        if(command[0].contains(prefix+"8ball")){
            eightBallCommand.onMessageCreate(event);
            return;
        }
        if(command[0].contains(prefix+"userinfo")){
            userInfoCommand.onMessageCreate(event);
            return;
        }

        if(command[0].contains(prefix+"whois")){ 
            nijiMemberCommand.onMessageCreate(event);
            return;
        }
        if(command[0].contains(prefix+"convert")){
            currencyConverterCommand.onMessageCreate(event);
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

For this class, I have a configurationManager for it

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationManager {
    @Bean
    public CommandManager commandManager() {
        return new CommandManager("!");
    }
}
```

The command that I want to test is **!whois noraneko** which will lead me to NijiMemberCommand.java

```
@Component
public class NijiMemberCommand implements MessageCreateListener {
    @Autowired
    MemberListService memberListService;

    private static org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);

    @Override
    public void onMessageCreate(MessageCreateEvent event){

        String[] command = event.getMessageContent().split(" ");
        if (command.length == 1) {
            logger.info("Will it enter here? no?");
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("You are missing argument, the command is consist of !member <name of liver>");
            return;
        }
        
        event.getChannel().sendMessage(memberListService.visual(command[1]));
        logger.info("Please enter here..... " + command[1] + " " + memberListService.visual(command[1]));
        event.getChannel().sendMessage(memberListService.visual(command[1]));
        return;

    }
}
```

Until this point, there is nothing wrong until it reached to `event.getChannel().sendMessage(memberListService.visual(command[1]));` which in my mind it should lead me to my Service layer which is this

```
@Service
public class MemberListServiceImpl implements MemberListService {
    @Autowired
    MemberListDB memberListDB;

    private static org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);

    public String capitalize(String name){
        return name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
    }
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public String visual(String nama) {
        logger.info("Masuk "+ nama);
        String[] name = nama.split(" ");
        String result =null;
        for(String e : name){
            result+=capitalize(e)+" ";
        }
        return memberListDB.showVisual(result);
    }
}
```

and this is my DB

```
@Repository
@EnableJpaRepositories
public interface MemberListDB extends JpaRepository<MemberListModel, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select m.visual FROM member_list as m, nickname AS n WHERE n.nick_id = m.nick AND n.nickname=:w", nativeQuery = true)
    String showVisual(@Param("w") String nama);
}
```

I tried to run a similar query within my PHPmyadmin, it shows non-null value
[image]

Where did I go wrong?

**// Edit**

This is my model that I use for my program

```
package com.nijicord.nijiworld.db.Model;



import com.nijicord.nijiworld.db.Repository.MemberListDB;
import com.sun.istack.NotNull;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * This is the table model that will hold the majority of member's info
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "member_list")
public class MemberListModel implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "nick")
    private Long nick_id;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "social_media")
    private Long social_id;


    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "branch")
    private String branch;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "debut_3d")
    private boolean debut;


    @Column(name = "illustrator")
    private String illustrator;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "visual")
    private String visual;

    public Long getNick_id() {
        return nick_id;
    }

    public void setNick_id(Long nick_id) {
        this.nick_id = nick_id;
    }

    public Long getSocial_id() {
        return social_id;
    }

    public void setSocial_id(Long social_id) {
        this.social_id = social_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getBranch() {
        return branch;
    }

    public void setBranch(String branch) {
        this.branch = branch;
    }

    public boolean isDebut() {
        return debut;
    }

    public void setDebut(boolean debut) {
        this.debut = debut;
    }

    public String getIllustrator() {
        return illustrator;
    }

    public void setIllustrator(String illustrator) {
        this.illustrator = illustrator;
    }

    public String getVisual() {
        return visual;
    }

    public void setVisual(String visual) {
        this.visual = visual;
    }
}
```

**////Edit**
This is the error

```
2020-12-20 15:37:54.405 ERROR 11840 --- [utorService - 1] o.j.core.util.event.EventDispatcherBase  : Unhandled exception in a listener thread for FFJ THREAD EMPORIUM!

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.nijicord.nijiworld.command.NijiMemberCommand.onMessageCreate(NijiMemberCommand.java:27) ~[main/:na]
    at com.nijicord.nijiworld.command.CommandManager.onMessageCreate(CommandManager.java:44) ~[main/:an]
```

**//////Edit**
I have edited my original post with the flow and the code.

Comment: Do you see the string "Masuk the_name_that_was_passed" in the log?

Comment: It doesn't come out.

Comment: ok. What about command.length? What is it equal to?

Comment: The command length is 2

Comment: How is the table defined?

Comment: I have edited my main post with the model that I use

Comment: Can you show us which line is line 27 ?

Comment: it is `logger.info("Please enter here..... " + command[1] + " " + memberListService.visual(command[1]));` inside the command function.

Comment: Well you can add an breakpoint here and see which part is null here. Keep us updated.

Comment: I have found the which part that is null and that is `memberListService.visual(command[1])` which it doesn't even enter to my Service layer. My guess right now is probably due to annotation but I have no clue on wether if my guess is right or no and if it is... I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: could you upload your whole application class and edit namespaces of `NijiMemberCommand`, `MemberListServiceImpl` classes?

Comment: I have edited my post with the flow and the code.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `nama.toUpperCase()` here.

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public String visual(String nama) {
        logger.info("Masuk "+ nama);
        return memberListDB.showVisual(nama.toUpperCase());
    }
```

But in query you are using nickname in **lowercase** e.g. `noraneko`. I think this might be a problem. You are using **uppercase** instead of **lowercase**.

Comment: I use uppercase due to within my database it is "Noraneko" instead of "noraneko". That is why I use uppercase, so if I input either "noraneko" or "Noraneko" - It will return my intended result

Comment: nama.toUpperCase() will make noraneko to NORANEKO, not Noraneko. Does NORANEKO return your intended result ?

Comment: Ah, probably that is why it return null. I will try to find a command where it can convert it to "Noraneko" instead and try it. If it runs properly, I will mark this post as the answer.

Comment: You can monitor sql with parameters in logs. set org.hibernate.SQL to debug and org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql to trace. It will show you the exact SQL and the params.

Comment: I tried it but I just realize that the problem is not inside the SQL itself since within the Service - The log that should be showing "Masuk Noraneko" but when I run it, it only shows NullPointerException. I will add the detail of the error in my original post.